# HTML email with click to show feature?

Tags: html, css, html-email, email

I am currently designing an email as the the content is huge i want to add a button to make a section visible or hide . I know email clients doesn't support any scripting inside the mail. Please let me know any other solution to have this feature.

Comment: I've coded a lot of emails in my time i've never come across a show hide function that would work across all email clients. There maybe something out there for specific email client but unlikely. Perhaps just use a 'read more' button that links to online version?

Comment: I would add this. I don't know what email you are gone send out (newsletter)? Generally if you need this function then you/that person/the company is going the wrong way about email. I would say that your best option is to have a link to a web version of the email.

Answer (score 2):

You actually can create an show/hide on click Element with CSS only, if you use a hidden checkbox, but this is more a workaround than an actual solution. You may want to search for this on SO or Google, but I **highly doubt**, that this will work with Email Clients, since most of them allow only inline CSS and only support some of the CSS properties.

So, since I actually never received an HTML Mail from any company, which had this behavior inside of the mail, I would say this is not possible with the current methods, or a least not possible without some dirty workarounds that may work or not on every client.

Answer (score 0):

I don't  think this is possible, What you could do is to redirect the user to a specific page with the additional content of the email

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using checkboxes and `:checked` in your CSS. However the huge caveat is it won't work everywhere (as is the case with most stuff in email), you're basically limited to having it work on iOS devices and Apple Mail.

So if you wanted this functionality in Outlook or Webmails (hotmail/gmail/yahoo), i'm afraid it's not possible at all.